# How can I capture packets from a PPP interface with pypcap?

Tags: python, pcap, packet-capture, ppp

It's `dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(pkt)` for an ethernet interface, what is it for the `ppp0` interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mixing up [dpkt](http://code.google.com/p/dpkt/), a library for parsing and creating packets, with [pypcap](http://code.google.com/p/pypcap/), a Python wrapper for libpcap.

To specify an interface to listen on, use `pcap.pcap(name='ppp0')`.

To deserialize PPP packets, use `dpkt.ppp.PPP(pkt)`.